# visual studio 13 crash after right click

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

I work on visual studio 2013, and in recent days every time I right click inside c# file I get message: "visual studio 2013 stopped working".
I tried to repair installation, but did not work.
in the event viewer I found the error:

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.   Exception
>   Info: System.AccessViolationException

in google search I did not find something except of reinstall visual studio, but I prefer avoiding it.

Comment: do you use any extensions / addins?

Comment: no, anyway not new extension/addin.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you have 2 graphic processors on PC :

switch (graphic.card.name on my PC)
{
   case "Intel " : VisualStudio.Crashed();

                   RightClickMouse on VS.ShortCut
                   Select("Run with graphic processor");
                   Click on morePowerfulProc :-)
                   BeHappy; 
                   break;
   case "NVIDIA" : VisualStudio.WorkingGood(); break;
}
```

i have two graphic processors on my PC. I don't know why but any VisualStudio working correct only with Nvidia graphic card;

Comment: I did not nuderstand what you want to say. how can I solve it?